# Create math function with a 'dummy' variable to be evaluated later

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in python which will add a bunch of math terms together which include some arbitrary variable name to be evaluated after the entire thing has been constructed. So for example

```
def transform(terms, xterm):
    function=.5
    step=terms
    odd=1
    while step>0:
        function+=(2/odd*np.pi)*np.sin(odd*np.pi*xterm)
        odd+=2
        step-=1
    return function

test=transform(10,somexvariable) 
print test
```

This is a Fourier series for a particular function I had to do in my mechanics class.

Basically I want to, for amount of terms (say 5), create a variable that looks like this:

```
function = .5 + (2/odd*np.pi)*np.sin(odd*np.pi*xvariable) +.......
```

out to however many terms I want where the variable 'odd' is the only number that changes.

The key and the difficulty to this problem is inserting some dummy variable I called 'xvariable' so that later I can create a array like this:

```
x2 = np.arange(0,10,.05)
y = transform(2,x2)
```

The result would be an array of those x values evaluated in the function I created with 'transform'.

I am sure I am going about this the wrong way...but I can't seem to figure out the necessary order of steps to make this work.

Help please. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [`numpy.vectorize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is what you are looking for?

Comment: `'.5'` is a string. `0.5` is a float literal.

Comment: You're right...the '.5' is an artifact of my trying a different method...just forgot to take the quotes off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).  It allows you to create a function with some of the arguments pre-filled.

```
from functools import partial

def sum_powers(x, terms):
    result = 0
    for term in terms:
        result += term ** x
    return result

sum_squares = partial(sum_powers, x=2)
sum_squares(terms=[1, 2, 3])
# 14

sum_cubes = partial(sum_powers, x=3)
sum_cubes(terms=[1, 2, 3])
# 36
```

Comment: This code isn't running for me. I am getting an error:

sum_powers() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'